# Can not connect to IRC Hackerzvoice channel by python?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, irc

I am trying to code a small program, which can connect to irc channel then send and receive messages. I succeed to connect to irc server, however I can't JOIN to any channel. I tried command `JOIN #channel` but I got nothings, no responding from server.
This is my code:

```
try:
  con = socket.socket()
  con = socket.create_connection((client.svhost, client.svport))
  print(('CONNECTING TO.. %s\r\n' % client.svhost).encode())
  con.send(('NICK %s \r\n' % client.user).encode())
  con.send(('USER %s %s root-me :%s \r\n' %(client.user, client.svhost, client.user)).encode())

  con.send(('JOIN %s' %client.channel).encode())


  print('Joined to.. %s\r\n' %client.channel)

  while True:
    respond = ""
    respond = con.recv(1024).strip().decode()

    print(respond)

    #PING - PONG
    pp = respond.split()
    if pp[0] == 'PING':
      print(pp)
      con.send(('PONG %s' %pp[1]).encode())
      print(('PONG %s' %pp[1]).encode())
      print('Responded')

      con.send(('JOIN %s' %client.channel).encode()) 

except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  sys.exit(1)
```

Thank for readding!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add **NewLine** character when sending the **Pong response** and you added a **JOIN** request before identified by the server.

**Change:**

```
con.send(('PONG %s' %pp[1]).encode()) # Change this line
con.send(('PONG %s\r\n' %pp[1]).encode()) # To This line
```

Also you will need to remove the **Join** before the registration (actually identified as a user in the server).

```
con.send(('JOIN %s' %client.channel).encode())
print('Joined to.. %s\r\n' %client.channel)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to remove the **JOIN** before registation but I got the same result. I could not connect to the channel that I need to reach.

Comment: Did you succeed connecting to the server ? If so this is just a JOIN problem and not registration problem as it was before.

Comment: I succeed connecting to server, but I could not connect to channel